# Full calendar day render doing nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

I'm trying to colour todays date on fullcalendar using day render, but no matter what I do, it doesn't seem to work!

Javascript

```
var events = <?php echo $eventsArray ?>;
var blocked = <?php echo $blockedArray ?>;
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();
console.log(blocked);
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(blocked).length; i++) {
 console.log(blocked[i].date);
}
$('#democalendarfull').fullCalendar({
 header: {
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
 },
  editable: false,
  aspectRatio: 2,
  droppable: false,
  events: events,
  dayRender: function (date, cell) {
  var today = new Date();
   if (date.getDate() === today.getDate()) {
    cell.css("background-color", "red");
   }
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="democalendarfull" class="mb">
                  <div class="panel green-panel no-margin">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <div id="date-popover" class="popover top" style="cursor: pointer; disadding: block; margin-left: 33%; margin-top: -50px; width: 175px;">
                              <div class="arrow"></div>
                              <h3 class="popover-title" style="disadding: none;"></h3>
                              <div id="date-popover-content" class="popover-content"></div>
                          </div>

                             //JAVASCRIPT IS INSIDE HERE

                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
```

Everything I add to change the date using day render doesn't change the calendar at all.

Comment: What does console.log(date.getDate()); return just before your if statement

Comment: That could be the problem, it doesn't return anything :S alert doesn't work either

Comment: It looks like anything I put inside the day render just doesnt run, even an alert, any idea why this could be?

Comment: is the calendar rendering at all?

Comment: it could also be the view you are in

Comment: The calendar is rendering and running fine with all of my events

Comment: can you try another callback function and see if other callback functions are working. ex viewRender: function(view)

Comment: If I use all of the js you have with my answer in the if statement it all works for me so if you get the callback working it should work right after

Comment: What version of fullcalendar are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in the if statement doing

```
if (date._d.getDate() === today.getDate())
```

date._d should be a format that getDate() accepts

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

It was a combination of version and format.

I upgraded my fullcalendar which then allowed me to run the dayrender function, but I then had to swap my format like Daffy suggested for it to work.